# How to roll the viewport?

Tags: interface, 3d-view

How do I rotate the viewport around the local (to the view port) - Z axis?

Basically what you would  get if you were to hit <kbd>R</kbd> with the camera selected in camera view.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: MW] ScrollWheel</kbd>, or <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 4</kbd> and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 6</kbd>.

---

Currently the scrollwheel binding doesn't exist in 2.8, however you can add it back yourself. Under *User Preferences > Input > 3D View > 3D View (Global)*, press *Add New* and set the operator to `view3d.view_roll`. Create a binding for both left and right:

[image]

Comment: Re: @squarespiral's comment on the other answer, you can refine the roll increment on either/both of these methods by going (in Blender 2.79 anyway) to User Preferences > Input > 3D View > 3D View (Global), scrolling down to the block of "View Roll" settings, clicking on the "expand" triangle of the one you want to change, selecting "Roll Angle" from the dropdown on the bottom right, and then typing a Roll Angle in the input box on the left (in radians, I think; I find a setting of -0.02 for Ctrl-Shift-ScrollWheelUp and 0.02 for down works really nicely for fine tuning with the mouse wheel).

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+ScrollWheel` apparently does not work (anymore) in Blender 2.80 beta, found no replacement either. The other two shortcuts work fine though.

Comment: @SimonRepp It works for me on latest master (1c5860407068)

Comment: @gandalf3 Are the beta builds on the website based on master? If yes I'll gladly try with the next release then :) Thanks for the info!

Comment: @SimonRepp I believe they are. However, I just remembered that I actually re-added the bindings myself (if I load factory settings it no longer works). I'll update my answer.

Comment: For those in 2.831+ the accurate location is Preferences > Keymap >3d View > 3D View(Global) ; the chain in the answer does not exist (Input has no sub of 3D View as it is now in Keymap). Let me know if I've misunderstood, but this works for me.

Answer (score 9):

One non optimal method is to bring the camera to the viewport(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numberpad 0</kbd>), select the camera and hit <kbd>R</kbd>. This isn't the neatest method, but it still works. It also offers to the degree precision. once positioned, you can delete the camera if it bugs you. see [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15052/how-do-i-un-roll-the-viewport) on how to "un-roll" the viewport once you're done.

Comment: For higher rotation precision this is better than the accepted answer - with Shift you have pretty good control.

Answer (score 0):

**Blender 3.5**

I wasn't able to expose the RNA controls in a new keymap, so instead, I changed the existing NDOF "View Roll" keymaps.  There is one for ClockWise and one for CounterClockWise.

Keymaps: 3D View: View Roll

Set to Mouse

WheelDown  (WheelUp for CCW)

Shift & Ctrl  (or your preference)

Roll: 0.2  (-0.2 for CCW)

https://prnt.sc/J5gwBDDsM6Xp