# How do I "un-roll" the viewport?

Tags: workflow, 3d-view

Lets say that I've rolled the view port with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: MW] Scrollwheel</kbd>, and now want to get it back to its original orientation. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Numpad 7,3 or 1</kbd>. When you navigate out of the view, it will be reset.

Comment: This only works until you select the next object with `/` which will roll the camera of the view port again.