# Is there any way to get a specific angle using the knife tool?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, knife-tool

Instead of the constrained 45 degrees that happens when you press <kbd>C</kbd>, is there a specific angle I can get for example 35 degrees instead?

It's currently cut at 45 degrees in the attached image and I need it to be 35.
[image: model cut at 45deg]

Comment: Currently there isn't such a function as far as I know.

Comment: It seem like it could be doable. Other tools allows allow for model numerical input.  This would be a good topic for BF-Funboard.

Comment: I agree this would be nice to have :) As MarcClintDion said, You might want to send a request along to the bf-funboard mailing list: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1190/599. Though at the moment the developers are pretty busy releasing 2.74..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a work around.
For a simple object like your cylinder, simply rotate it in object mode 35°, make the cut, then rotate the object back.
[image: animated gif]

For more complex objects where you can not rotate it. You can align the view to a rotated face. You could duplicate a face out of your mesh and separate it in to a new object, or just add a new object, a plane or an empty; then align the view to it with  with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>NumPad 7</kbd>.

[image: animated gif12346]

Finally do not forget that you can [roll the view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15049/2217), but that is limited to 15° increments.

Answer (score 14):

This currently isn't directly possible with the knife tool, but it is possible with a few other tools:

## [Knife Project](http://blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html?#knife-project)

1. Add a plane and rotate it the desired amount (e.g. <kbd>R</kbd> 35°)
2. Align the view along the axis you want to cut
3. With both the plane and the target object selected, enter edit mode (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>) and press *knife project* in the tool shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>)

[image]

## [Boolean modifier](http://blender.org/manual/modifiers/generate/booleans.html)

1. Again, add a plane and rotate it the desired amount
2. Select the target object and add a boolean modifier
3. Specify the plane as the boolean object

[image]

One advantage to this method is that you can non-destructively change the angle and position of the cut at any time.

## [Mesh Intersect](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.72/Modeling)

1. Select the target object and enter edit mode
2. Add a plane
3. Select the plane. You can quickly select disconnected geometry by hovering over it and pressing <kbd>L</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>Space</kbd>*> Intersect*

[image]