# Rotate view around Y-axis

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode

I'd like to be able to rotate my VIEW (not my model, not my camera either) around the Y-axis. This would allow me to select some vertices using a box selection. I fear it cannot be done, but I hope some one proves me wrong.

My research so far is little promising:

http://forums.cgsociety.org/archive/index.php/t-981266.html

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_HotKeys/3D_View/Object_Mode

Q: How to rotate my view around the Y-axis?

Comment: Does this help? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15049/how-to-roll-the-viewport It's hard to tell from your question what you mean as you don't state which axis you are currently facing.

Comment: Indeed, it does help! I used the word 'rotate' instead of 'roll' to search this forum, so I didn't find the post.

I try to rotate the viewport around the global Y-axis. The answer is to use (on Mac, at least) CTRL + SHIFT + SCROLLWHEEL.

Answer (score 3):

Appearently, I created a duplicate of: [How to roll the viewport?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15049/how-to-roll-the-viewport)

For a quick answer:

use CTRL + SHIFT + SCROLLWHEEL.

Thanks to  @Ray Mairlot

Comment: You don't need to worry about answering this, I have marked the question as a duplicate and if you/others agree it will be closed and the duplicate will be linked to.

Answer (score 2):

these are the shortcuts for view orbit :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>MMB</kbd>  rotate view around global Z axis

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>MMB</kbd> rotate the view around the view horizontal axis

for your case :

- press <kbd>3</kbd> to get in Right view
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>MMB</kbd> to rotate around the y axis

Comment: I'm sorry, those combination do not give the right result. They work the same as when I would press 8 & 2  or    4  &  6    on the numpad.