# How do I rotate face normals verticies (not flip!)

Tags: modeling, mesh, normals

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with an issue where some of the face normals are "upside down". They are not reversed, just upside down. I'm using 2.75.

This is the same problem [reported at the forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20151024114919/https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25783).

[image: cubes with normals where one is up and the other is down]

The problem is that some face normals have the X and Y axis off - either 180 degrees like in the right cube above, or 90 degrees. All the normals are facing outward. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>N</kbd> doesn't solve/change anything. I've even deleted the face and rebuild it and it keeps the same upside down.

This affects me using some features like *Align View to Active* since almost every other face I'm working with in my model are reversed.

Comment: AFAIK [blender just doesn't have support for this](https://developer.blender.org/T33317) atm, at least without cumbersome hacks like *Separate* (`Y`), *Rotate* (`R Z Z`), *Select All* (`A A`), *Merge Doubles* (`W R`). Note that blender [*does* have a way to roll the view](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15049/599) now, ([unlike when that bug was reported](https://developer.blender.org/T33317#165171))

Comment: Yup - I saw the ability to roll the view, its just very cumbersome moving between different faces where sometimes the view is right side up and other is down. Then on top of that I have to keep looking if I was locking an action on an axis I have to keep seeing if it is x or y. Its just very painful. For a few I'll take a look at the cumbersome hacks.