# Lasso select in straight lines?

Tags: vertices, selection-tools

I'm using the "lasso" selection tool by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and dragging the left mouse button in edit mode in order to select a group of vertices inside the selected area. However, my mouse hand isn't very good at drawing straight lines, and I keep selecting vertices that I don't want. I can select like the top shape, but need to select in straight lines like the bottom shape:

[image]

Is there such a thing as a "straight lasso" select tool, instead of the freehand one? I've tried using the <kbd>B</kbd> keyboard shortcut to select in a square, but I need to be able to draw my own polygonal shape.

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing beyond *Border Select* (`B`key by default)

Comment: Have you tried the **C** button? Press **C** button, then hold *LMB* and drag the cursor to select the desired vertices.

Comment: @PaulGonet, that's a very helpful tool, thanks! It definitely helps in those narrow areas. Also discovered that `+` key makes the selection larger, and middle button deselects the painted vertices.

Comment: @Marco Del Valle Instead of using the **+** button you may just scroll the *Mouse Wheel*. BTW Is this the tool you're looking for?

Comment: @PaulGonet that also works. It's not exactly the tool that I was looking for, as I was looking for a tool that would let you make selections in straight lines, instead of hand-drawing, but this one definitely helps.

Comment: While box select doesn't give you diagonal selection lines, you could try doing it in multiple steps which will keep adding more to the existing selection - B-drag B-drag B-drag - if you have one hand on mouse and one on keyboard it is quick enough. Also middle mouse deselects same as circle select.

Comment: The only possible way for you is a bit tricky, and inefficient. but works: 1.  Ctrl + LMB click continuously to create lines. 2. select all lines then press F to fill it as a polygon. 3. Make sure the new polygon is on top of all elements based on your view, and the Limit Selection button is disabled on header, then use B tool to select all visible verts, then invert the selection. Now you should get the expected selection. Finally you may want to delete that polygon.

Comment: You could also [roll the viewport](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15049/how-to-roll-the-viewport), after that all the lines you draw with Lasso tool will be angular relatively to the usual view. That is, Lasso doesn't handle straight lines, unfortunately.

Comment: @LeonCheung HAHA! That's a clever approach, but as you said, not very efficient.

Comment: Yep. Oops, seems I make a typo: Disabled means Enabled.  :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no polygon select tool in Blender (yet) but you can hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> after your first selection and Blender will create a path to the next vertex you right click. There are some settings in the Tool panel to adjust it's behavior. If your selection path is closed you can press <kbd>H</kbd> to hide, which then enables you to <kbd>L</kbd> link select the island. <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> and you get the whole gang. A bit of a work around but can be handy.

[image]

Comment: For selecting what is inside of loopcut use *Select Loop Inner Region* to skip hiding.

Comment: Yep - that works sometimes...but had some weird results with it also...

Comment: Thanks! Very useful. Still not quite the same as a straight lasso, since it needs edges connecting the vertices for it to work, but it's the closest solution I've seen so far!