# How to always have the local Z axis pointing upwards in the viewport?

Tags: transforms, coordinates

I am editing an object, use local transform orientation.

Here it is

[image: local transform orientation]

Why is not Z, the blue arrow pointing "screen upwards"?

That would make life so my easier!

Comment: As it's seen on the screenshot you probably rolled the viewport with everything there, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15049/how-to-roll-the-viewport. In this case Z could be pointing upwards but you will see like it doesn't. Generally it is useful to use Normal transform orientation or create a custom one and move along them.

Answer (score 4):

World Transform and Local Transform exists for reasons.

You can reset/apply your object's transform to make your Local Z axis pointing upward.  But there is no way to lock Z axis to point upward.  What you can try is to move/rotate your object's mesh in Edit mode, in there, your rotation/move operations won't change the local axis's orientation.

Comment: Wow, that is depressing. The rotation contains information that I just dont want to change. I do not want to rotate the object in edit mode, because I do not want to rotate the object! Just to edit it with a locked axis.

Comment: I'm not sure if I actually understood your question correctly.  Were you asking about whether it's normal to have the 3Dview Grids and Z pointing at that direction as your image showed, or are you actually asking about the Local Z axis aligning with the world Z axis.  The world Z always points upward.  Unless you rotate your view in a weird way.

Comment: You can align the view's orientation so that it matches that of your objects local coordinates. Select the object and press shift+numpad 1, 3, or 7

Comment: I need to edit my object having Z pointing upwards. Else, I feel very clumsy.

Comment: Define upward...  Z, always point upward IMHO, difference is one that is global, one is local.  Z is the upward/downward direction for local transformation.

Comment: I have written "screen upwards" in the question.

Comment: I'm amused I even got 4 upvotes then.  My answer is completely irrelevant to what you are asking after all.  Facepalm.