# How can I use Cylinder Mapping on a complicated object?

Tags: uv

I have an object which is made up of cylinders, but all at different angles. I thought I could just do a cylinder map on each different section and set the angle of the cylinder map (Like in Maya), but it doesn't seem to have that option. I can choose 'align to object' which works as expected for the vertical cylinder section, but it won't work for the other two sections.

How can I easily map the other sections?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: yes it doesn't seem to be possible unless you rotate the cylinder 90°. You could get around with another mode like Follow Active Quads: Select the whole cylinder, then select whatever face of this cylinder (make it the active face), then unwrap with this option, you'll get the same result as the Cylinder Projection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Cylindrical, Spherical](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/uv/unwrapping/mapping_types.html#cylinder-and-sphere-projection) and Cubic texture projections in Blender are oriented by aligning an orthographic **view** before executing the <kbd>U</kbd> unwrap command with one of the options in the window with that view.

You can have other 3D views open to keep an eye on things.

On a roughly cylindrical selection of your model you can:

- Look directly across its equator, with its poles up and down.
- That's <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> with a latitude loop of edges (temporarily created and?) selected
- You may have to [revive the keyboard shortcut](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15051/35559) for rolling the viewport
- Use options something like these:

[image]

Or you can:

- Look directly down one of its poles
- That's <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> with a polar face (temporarily created and?) selected
- Don't forget you can <kbd>H</kbd> hide parts of your mesh to make these operations easier
- And use options something like these:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! that is exactly what I was looking for!