# How do you pan zoom rotate the viewport while drawing with the grease pencil tool?

Tags: 3d-view, grease-pencil, navigation

I'm an illustrator and I use photoshop to create my work on a flat surface. At least there, I can zoom, pan, rotate my illustration to completion.

How the heck do you pan zoom rotate the viewport while drawing in blender use the pencil tool?

I use a stylus and have a pen display and I freehand draw with my right hand. how can I pan zoom rotate the canvas with my left hand?

Are there any hot keys? or do I have to drop my stylus just to press the numpad?

Comment: Blender's navigation is heavily dependent on the middle mouse button. I map the bottom button on my stylus to the middle mouse button, so I can use the keymaps @susu describes just a bit easier.

Comment: I map the bottom button to right click, the top one to middle button. After a few minutes it becomes quite easy to navigate.

Answer (score 2):

What works for me using a wacom tablet is to enable "emulate 3 button mouse".

That way I can draw with one hand, and with the other I press <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and press and move the sytuls to Zoom in or out.

To rotate press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press on the stylus.

To pan press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and move by pressing the stylus.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> will let you erase without changing the tool.

To roll the view you need to create a new keyboard binding so that you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and the <kbd>scroll wheel</kbd> on the mouse.

Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15051/92768