# How do I look top down in blender, but at a different orientation?

Tags: 3d-view

I was wanting to look top down at my scene, which I do by clicking on the Blue Z in the top right corner. However, when I click that Z, no matter which way I was facing, I am always looking with the positive Y in front and the positive X on the right, is there any way that I can look top down but at a different angle?

Comment: you can make the view rotate with 4 and 6 but I guess this is not what you want

Comment: Yes, I am aware that I can look side on from different angles, but I want to be able to look top down from different angles

Comment: Do you mean the orthographic <-> perspective view? Use Numpad_7 for top view and then you can toggle the view with Numpad_5 (or click the grid icon below the camera icon and the gizmo (XYZ control))

Comment: I think he means he wants to rotate the orthographic view in 2D. Like rotating the canvas.

Comment: If you mean you want to roll the camera, [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15051/35559) will probably help. The suggested key-bindings still work in 3.0